# How can I persist local-storage items from a Cordova application to phone?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

So I've developed an app that saves contacts via local-storage. My problem is every time I update the app or uninstall it, the item is deleted too.

I see that using SQLite storage will do the same also.

Is there a way to persist it to the phone so the data can be saved whenever I update the app? Thanks.

Comment: You can save it to a file.

Comment: Care to elaborate sir? @Fahadsk

Comment: write your data in file and save it to device memory just like you save any other file in the device storage

Answer (score 2):

If you want these contacts to remain only available in your app (i.e not add them to the global Contacts list), and if there's not too much data (less than 1Mb on iOS but unlimited on Android), then you could use [cordova-plugin-cloud-settings](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-cloud-settings) which backs up data in the cloud (Android auto-backup / iCloud).

This ensures the data persists between app uninstall/re-install.

Comment: Thank you! Will take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

you'd have migrate from `window.localStorage` to [SQLite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) or [Preferences](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-app-preferences)

... or even to [Contacts](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/), because we are talking about contacts here.

Comment: Thank you. I've also thought of syncing it to the cloud, since I am using firebase.

Comment: @sorxrob it depends, if these are contacts which should only be available to your app vs. contacts, which should be added into the device's contacts (these would also be synced - and the app would be able to access them all - with the condition, that this permission had been granted by the user).

Comment: Thanks for the info sir! Would definitely read more about this.